# How do I prevent Access locking database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an Microsoft Access application that has a "continous forms" subform.  When accessing that form in my application I have discovered that SQL Server has "a lot" of locks (over 1000). [Found by doing a select 1000 records from master database view sys.dm_trans_locks].

The data source for the form is a Pass Through Query called qryProspect summary.  It in turn just has the SQL "EXEC qryProspectSummary" to call a stored procedure which returns the required data.

the Stored Procedure "qryProspectSummary" is just a complex select statement - with some nested selects and unions and joins over several tables.  Running it from SQL Server Management studio produces the correct results and doesn't lock any parts of the database.

I have set the datasource recordset type to "snapshot".

How can I prevent Access taking out all these locks - it effectively destroys any multi-user working for what is supposed to be just a data snapshot.

Comment: Have you looked at NOLOCK ( http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/nolock-on-view-stored-proce/40229 )?

Comment: I am aware NOLOCK exists - but one thing I discovered when I ran a profile on the requests to SQL Server was that locking was being done by ACCESS immediately after it gets the results from the stored procedure, not by SQL Server during the execution of the stored procedure.  The locks remain in place until Access closes the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a linked view to return the results for this snapshot.  I have found in some cases that Access uses a view much better when dealing with large data sets from SQL Server.  Is there any way you can use **qryProspectSummary** as a view?  This is not guaranteed to work but is one option that I would try.

Comment: I have it working via another method, so I haven't tried this.  I do use Views in the application to great effect, but one difficulty with views is that you can't ORDER the output in the view definition (I know ACCESS could order them but this is inefficient).   One very important aspect of this query is the order it returns the rows

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?  [There is a hot fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926292) in 2008 that enables using an order by in a view.

Comment: I'm using Sql Server Express 2008 R2. Have I made a mistake with ordering in views?

Comment: The ordering of views is a bit strange - from what I can read it doesn't actually the order items are returned, but just insures that if you have a TOP 90 PERCENT for instance that the correct 90 percent are passed through.

Comment: I have now re-implemented this part of the application as a view and then attached a linked table to this view as part of application startup.  The continuous form I refer to above has SQL which selects all from view and adds the order by that I need.  I then can filter on the results much faster than re-calling the stored procedure. [And incidentally implementing the view and finding it gave different answers to the stored procedure should an incorrect handling of nulls].  I am therefore marking this answer as the best one for me

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem yesterday, but for some reason couldn't access this site.  Instead of creating a passthrough query with the access to the stored procedure, I instead added the following code to the ON LOAD event of the form.

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command, rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = getStrConn
cmd.CommandText = "qryProspectSummary"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Set rst = cmd.Execute()
Set Me.Form.Recordset = rst
Set cmd = Nothing
```

getStrConn is a function which retries the database connection string (I have an admin feature to change databases on startup, so I can't just hardcode it).
This solves the problem and I find that nothing out of the ordinary is now getting locked when I open the form.

It does have one downside, I was using Form.Requery, but that doesn't rerun the query - I have to re-execute the code above instead.  But its a small price to pay

Comment: Although this works functionally, it has issues with filtering which this application needs - I've had to actually pass parameters to the stored procedure and requery when all I really want to do is add or remove a filter on the results set.  So I am not sure its yet the right answer for the longer term.